# How do I convert the output of "getctime()" and "getmtime()" into the time format required by HTML's "published_time" and "modified_time" META tags?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, time, time-format

My website's articles are written using `.md` files, to get the created and modified times of these files I use the `os.path.getctime()` and `os.path.getmtime()` methods.

The output of these methods look like this:

- `1553541590.723329`
- `1553541590.723329`

While HTML requires this format:

- `2001-09-17T05:59:00+01:00`
- `2013-09-16T19:08:47+01:00`

I have two questions regarding this matter:

1. What's are the names of these two time formats?
2. How do I change the output of those methods to look like the required HTML format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) The [os.path](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) documentation indicates that both `os.path.getctime()` and `os.path.getmtime()` return a float indicating seconds since epoch. That seems consistent with the numbers you are getting.

2) The easiest thing to do would be to convert to an object to represent a date and then provide your desired format. Here, I used [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) with `strftime()` to output a string of desired format.

```
import datetime

>>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1553541590.723329)
datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 25, 12, 19, 50, 723329)

>>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1553541590.723329).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
'2019-03-25T12:19:50'
```

You may find it easiest to just add the time zone string on the end since adding a timezone to a datetime object is a little involved. If you do want to go through with it, you need to create a `tzinfo` object and use it to update the `datetime` object using `datetime.astimezone(tz)`. Here's a pretty good resource for [adding a timezone to a datetime object](https://howchoo.com/g/ywi5m2vkodk/working-with-datetime-objects-and-timezones-in-python).

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time and putting in the effort to answer this question, it made my day! Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Good luck with your project :)

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of trouble with my (now completed) project, I've awarded you a bounty to thank you.

Comment: How nice! And congratulations on the successful project. That's always a good feeling.

Comment: Clarification from Wikipedia about the Epoch time:
Unix time (also known as Epoch time, POSIX time, seconds since the Epoch, or UNIX Epoch time) is a system for describing a point in time. It is the number of seconds that have elapsed since the Unix epoch, minus leap seconds; the Unix epoch is 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970. Leap seconds are ignored, with a leap second having the same Unix time as the second before it, and every day is treated as if it contains exactly 86400 seconds. Due to this treatment, Unix time is not a true representation of UTC.

Comment: Until now still helpful!

Comment: Thank you, your answer resulted in the beautiful line of code: 

`datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(FILEPATH)).strftime('%y%m%d')`